# Is it possible to create a deep link from QPX Express API response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deep-linking, google-qpx-express-api

I'm building a small Rails flight search app built on top of Google's QPX Express API.
Does anyone know if it is possible to create a deep link (ie: I'd like to be able to send the user to a direct page on the airline's website for a given flight search) from the information given in the QPX response object? Possibly with info such as trips.tripOption[].id (the identifier uniquely identifying this trip in a response)? I'm hoping there is some systematic way to do it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed their support earlier this week and they came back with a no.